# Determine when guice initialises new instance of the Binder

Tags: java, ioc-container, guice

In one of our projects we use guice to set up the application's dependency tree. Due to special requirements we created an interface which extends the guice `Binder` interface. The implementation of that interface uses the implementation of the `Binder` interface provided by guice and adds some new functionality. While debugging the application I noticed that when `Guice.createInjector(Module... modules)` is called, the same binder is passed to each module. Initially I used the passed implementation of the `Binder` to create an instance that implements our interface, but that caused problems since each module worked with different instance. So my question is: Is there a hook I can use to create an instance of my implementation whenever guice creates new `Binder`? By hook I mean a class I can extend or something similar. Any idea will be appreciated.

Uros

Comment: Cant you just do something like bind(YourBinder.class).to(Binder.class); in the module?

Comment: @tom You mean bind(Binder.class).to(MyBinder.class)? The other way around won't work(compile time error) because MyBinder extends the Binder interface. Your solution sounds like the obvious one, but it does not work. I guess because i need my binder in the modules - before the injector is installed. So even though I bind the Binder interface to my implementation in the module that is called first, other modules still get called with the guice default Binder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

Class [`com.google.inject.spi.Elements`](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/core/src/com/google/inject/spi/Elements.java) does the whole binding work, see its internal class `RecordingBinder` which is created directly with `new`.

BTW, if you want to extend Guice internals I think you better not use anything outside `com.google.inject.spi` package. Most of access to Guice internals is provided from there, and if you do not see something there, then you probably want something wrong and unsupported.  `Binder` is one such thing.

Comment: So in your opinion the best solution would be to create my binder in the module that gets called first and store it in the static field and  than just retrieve it in subsequent modules? Btw I need a 'special' binder so it remembers which types were already bound to it and just ignore the subsequent bind instructions. I know it sounds like a problem in the design but our team works with other teams and that was a requirement. Any ideas how to implement this without extending the Binder provided by guide?

Comment: @Uroš, unfortunately, your whole approach is wrong. Prohibiting multiple bindings for the same key is deliberate design decision in Guice because it is usually an indicator that something goes wrong. Guice does not allow multiple bindings, unless one module is explicitly overridden with another module using `Modules.override()`. Because of this decision you are forced to have at most one binding for each key, which is very good - you always can find actual implementation you are binding to.

Comment: @Uroš, you can probably write a class like `AbstractModule` which will store custom binder in a static field and expose an API which will delegate to this custom binder. I don't think you will be able to do better than this. You also must take extra care if your program is multithreaded.

Comment: so there is no way to determine whether a specific key is already bound to the Binder?

Comment: @Uroš, yes, it is impossible, at least, Guice does not provide any API to do this (even real `Binder` implementation is internal class). You can get all bindings in an `Injector`, but only after it is created, when it is already late for your case.